# Document.scroll doesn’t work with multiple html pages

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have multiple html pages (Page A and Page B) and I need to detect if certain divs on each page are in view while the user is scrolling on either page. Both pages link to each other and share the same js script. The problem right now is that when I scroll and navigate to the other page, it only detects the divs for pageA but not for pageB. When I comment out the function for pageA (checkPageA()), then it works for pageB. I’m not sure what’s going on and why it’s not working for both pages.

I'm not sure how to show multiple html pages here, so here’s a simplified version of my code (doesn't run since the pages aren't connected here). I want to keep both pages separate HTML files and not combine them. Thanks!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).scroll(function() {
    checkPageA();
    checkPageB();
  });

  function checkPageA() {
    if (percentInViewport(".pageA", 10)) {
      alert("pageA");
    }
  }


  function checkPageB() {
    if (percentInViewport(".pageB", 10)) {
      alert("pageB");
    }
  }

  /**Checks if div is in the viewport by percentVisible**/
  function percentInViewport(objectString, percentVisible) {
    var el = document.querySelector(objectString);
    rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    windowHeight = (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight);
    return !(
      Math.floor(100 - (((rect.top >= 0 ? 0 : rect.top) / + -(rect.height / 1)) * 100)) < percentVisible ||
      Math.floor(100 - ((rect.bottom - windowHeight) / rect.height) * 100) < percentVisible
    )
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- HTML for Page A-->
<html>

<body>
  <a href="pageB.html">Go to Page B</a>
  <div class="pageA">This is page A</div>
</body>

</html>

<!-- HTML for Page B-->
<html>

<body>
  <a href="pageA.html">Go to Page A</a>
  <div class="pageB">This is page B</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: have you checked in console of pageB that any error related to . pageA

Comment: Ah yes, just figured this out through the console. Some error with another function in my code and now it works. thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I just figured this out. There was something wrong with my percentInViewport function due to the null elements. As someone suggested, did some debugging from the console and the scroll works haha. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue with you code because when you are on the second page the checkPageA function is called when you scroll and the class that is given in is not found and it will give error.

instead of creating different function, and different class for every page you can use one common function and one common class.

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- HTML for Page A-->
<html>

<body>
  <a href="test1.html">Go to Page B</a>
  <div class="pageDiv">This is page A</div>
</body>

</html>


<!-- HTML for Page B-->
<html>

<body>
  <a href="test.html">Go to Page A</a>
  <div class="pageDiv">This is page B</div>
</body>

</html>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).scroll(function() {
    checkPage();
  });




  function checkPage() {
    if (percentInViewport(".pageDiv", 10)) {
      alert("pageDiv");
    }
  }

  /**Checks if div is in the viewport by percentVisible**/
  function percentInViewport(objectString, percentVisible) {
    var el = document.querySelector(objectString);
    rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    windowHeight = (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight);
    return !(
      Math.floor(100 - (((rect.top >= 0 ? 0 : rect.top) / + -(rect.height / 1)) * 100)) < percentVisible ||
      Math.floor(100 - ((rect.bottom - windowHeight) / rect.height) * 100) < percentVisible
    )
  }
})
</script>
```